# Aligning rows and columns outputted via nested loops - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm currently trying to calculate the windchill temperatures for the given temperature and windspeed list values and output them into a table, along with the temperatures on the y-axis and the windspeeds on the x-axis.
This is the code I have now:

```
windspeed = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50]
temperature = [-20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]

for i in windspeed:
    print("|{0:^6}|".format(str(i)), end='')
print()


for row in temperature:
  print(row, ":", end = ' ')
  if row == 1:
    continue
  for col in windspeed:
    if col > 3:
        windchill = float(35.74 + 0.6215*row) - (35.75*col**0.16) + (0.4275*row * col**0.16)
    else:
        windchill = row
    if row < 0 or col < 0:
        print("{0:>7.2f}".format(windchill), end='  ')  
    else:
        print("{0:>6.2f}".format(windchill), end='  ')  
  print()
```

And this is what the desired output looks like:

[image]

I've tried using a dictionary, where the windspeeds are the keys and the temperatures are the values. I've tried using the pandas module for tabulating and it's still not coming back how I want it to look.

Comment: "This is the code I have now:" **What happens** when you try this code? **How is that different** from your expectation? **Step by step**, what appears to happen as the code runs, and where does it appear to go wrong? Please read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and about how to create a [mre]. We don't debug code here, and we need a concrete description of a problem in order for there to be any **question**.

Comment: "I've tried using a dictionary, where the windspeeds are the keys and the temperatures are the values." **How** did you try this, and **what happened** when you tried it?

Comment: `if row == 1` this will never be true, There is no value `1` in the `temperature` list...

Comment: I'm confused about what you want your output to be, you've used print statements but you state that you want to tabulate the data. Karl's points are correct, your question needs more focus or needs to be better explained

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your first line printing the windspeed header is on the right track but it should allocate space for the temperature scale column.

You can use the same approach for each line by computing the chills in a list (or a generator).

Here's an example using unpacking to print complete lines with a | separator rather than calling print for each cell:

```
windspeed = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50]
temperature = [-20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]

print("      ",*map("{:^6}".format,windspeed),sep="|")
for tmp in temperature:
    print(*["------"]*(len(windspeed)+1),sep="|")
    chills = ( tmp if ws <= 3
               else 35.74 + 0.6215*tmp - 35.75*ws**0.16 + 0.4275*tmp*ws**0.16
               for ws in windspeed )
    print(f"{tmp:^6}",*map("{:^6.2f}".format,chills),sep="|")
```

output:

```
      |  0   |  5   |  10  |  15  |  20  |  25  |  30  |  35  |  40  |  45  |  50  
------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------
 -20  |-20.00|-34.00|-40.72|-45.01|-48.23|-50.83|-53.03|-54.93|-56.62|-58.14|-59.53
------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------
 -10  |-10.00|-22.26|-28.33|-32.21|-35.11|-37.46|-39.45|-41.17|-42.70|-44.07|-45.32
------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------
  0   | 0.00 |-10.51|-15.93|-19.40|-22.00|-24.09|-25.86|-27.40|-28.77|-29.99|-31.11
------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------
  10  |10.00 | 1.24 |-3.54 |-6.59 |-8.88 |-10.72|-12.28|-13.64|-14.84|-15.92|-16.90
------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------
  20  |20.00 |12.98 | 8.85 | 6.22 | 4.24 | 2.65 | 1.30 | 0.13 |-0.91 |-1.84 |-2.69 
------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------
  30  |30.00 |24.73 |21.25 |19.03 |17.36 |16.02 |14.88 |13.89 |13.02 |12.23 |11.52 
------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------
  40  |40.00 |36.47 |33.64 |31.84 |30.48 |29.39 |28.46 |27.66 |26.95 |26.31 |25.73 
------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------
  50  |50.00 |48.22 |46.04 |44.64 |43.60 |42.76 |42.04 |41.43 |40.88 |40.38 |39.93 
------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------
  60  |60.00 |59.96 |58.43 |57.45 |56.72 |56.13 |55.63 |55.19 |54.81 |54.46 |54.14
```